# Передача переменной в функцию

Tags: php, laravel

Как передать переменную `$id` в функцию `Sheetname`

```
        $id = 1;
        Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) {
           $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
              //Тут нужен вывод переменной `$id
              $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
           });
       })->export('xls');
```

Пробовал `global`, `public`, переменная не найденна

Answer (score 1, accepted):

это [замыкание](http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php), используйте use

```
    $id = 1;
    Excel::create('Filename', function($excel) use ($id) {
       $excel->sheet('Sheetname', function($sheet) {
          //Тут нужен вывод переменной `$id
          $sheet->setOrientation('landscape');
       });
   })->export('xls');
```